# How does Xcode autocomplete dynamic methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

For example, if you declare in your .h:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) Foo *bar`

In your .m you'll get an autocompletion for:

`+(NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingBar`

I know this is a feature of KVO, and I'm curious as to how this is implemented. Would it be possible to autocomplete `+(id)myOwnDynamicMethodForBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not something related to KVO, but related to a private framework called `DVTFoundation`, which is used by Xcode (DVT stands for Developer Toolkit). The framework, or in another word, Xcode, will detect what you typed in the editor and give you some suggestion for autocompletion. If you want to make your own dynamic method to be able to autocomplete (such as the form of `myOwnDynamicMethodFor<Key>`), you may have to implement a plug-in to change the autocompletion action for Xcode.

If you want to do so, you may have to see some plug-in tutorial, such as [WRITING YOUR OWN XCODE 4 PLUGINS](http://blacksmithsoftware.com/blog/2012/11/19/writing-your-own-xcode4-plugins) or [Creating an Xcode4 Plugin](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/creating-an-xcode4-plugin/). The popular Xcode plug-in [KSImageNamed](https://github.com/ksuther/KSImageNamed-Xcode) implemented a autocompletion feature for the method: -imageNamed:, will be a good example and start point for you.

Good luck~

Comment: Thanks, the KSImageNamed link is great. For my purposes I found it was better to just declare one `+(id)myOwnDynamicMethodForProperty:(NSString *)propertyName` method and pass in the name of the property as a string.